# Error Perl after upgrading

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, perl

After upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 I tried to use my program as usual which require Perl but I got this error:

> Encode.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb80080, needed 0xde00080).

or typing directly cpan:

> ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb80080, needed 0xde00080)

Has anyone of you experience on his issue?

How can I solve it?

Comment: In this [so Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000585/listutil-c-loadable-library-and-perl-binaries-are-mismatched-got-handshake-key) reboot solved the problem. Did you reboot your system after the upgrade?

Comment: Yep! Already done several times but no way to fix the issue!

Comment: When you had 17.04, did you install or upgrade any Perl modules using `cpan`, `cpanm`, or the manual install procedure (`perl Makefile.PL` etc.)?

Comment: Ya, I installed several modules manually and I guess this is the issue but I have no clue how to solve it and why did not cause any troubles before  upgrading and suddenly does?

Comment: A number of Perl modules need to be recompiled for each version of Perl; 17.04 comes with Perl 5.24 and 17.10 with Perl 5.26. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any "easy" way to fix this. Try `perl -V` and look for the `@INC` section, the offending modules (the ones you installed manually) will be in one of those directories, probably under `/usr/local`; also try `perldoc perllocal`. Since deleting things manually is a delicate procedure, maybe you could just look around in those directories for now and report back what you find.

Comment: In the future, I'd recommend to not install modules into the system Perl with anything other than the system package manager (`apt-get` and friends). If you need Perl modules that aren't available in the Ubuntu repositories, you can use [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) to install them locally in your home directory, or you can use [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/) to easily install your own copy of Perl.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I wonder if the issue is related to versions incompatibility, why the error message is so encrypted? on other hand  looking to fix this issue, I found out this that I have two perl versions: The command used: perl -e '-e "$_/List/Util.pm" and print $_ foreach @INC'.   and the output: /home/loubna/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base. I never installed another version of perl, I guess was installed automatically with cpan?

Comment: I never installed another version of perl, I guess was installed automatically with cpan? Would that be possible? I removed the version installed on my home directory and the command does not find cpan anymore.

Comment: `List::Util` is a "core" module that (almost) always gets installed with Perl, and there are several other modules that Ubuntu will install by default via other packages (usually named `libsomething-perl`). Anyway, the good thing here is that `/home/loubna/perl5/lib/perl5/` sounds like the directory that `local::lib` would use, which means that your custom-installed modules should all be contained in one place. Although you will have to reinstall those modules (use `local::lib` again!), it should be fairly safe to just delete `/home/loubna/perl5/lib`.

Comment: Please could you provide the full output of running "perl -V" to assist in figuring out what's going on here?

Comment: Please, could you tell me how can I post it? too long list!

Comment: You can edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Haukex, how can I edit a question if only 5 minutes after writing a text are provided to edit? Anyway, the problem is solved now. It turns out that my program Circos did not find Perl modules after upgrading, don't ask me why as I could run Perl from /usr/local and not Perl from home directory. As you said, it seems to be an issue of version incompatibility or modules updating. Now I deleted perl in /home/user and I installed the modules from scratch as is the easiest way for me to transfer them rather to use List::Util.

Comment: I guess this is not the optimal solution but indeed the easiest one for somebody who is not running fixing issues each day. Thank you all for your suggestions.